# the command only responds when I don't put an args it responds, but when I put it it doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, discord.js

the command only responds when I use it without args, when I put the argument that in this case, it is the new prefix it does not respond and does not log any errors

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args, db) => {
    
    if (args.length === 0){
        message.channel.send('Esta faltando o novo prefixo!')
    }else if (args.length === 1){
        let nPrefix = args[0];
        
        db.collection('guilds').doc(message.guild.id).update({
            'prefix' : nPrefix
        }).then(() => {
            message.channel.send(`[prefix update] : novo prefix : ${nPrefix}`);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could `args` ever have more than 1 element?

Comment: You have two conditions where any useful code runs ... args length is 0, or 1 ... any other length and nothing will happen

Comment: i did not understand, he continued with the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

try to :

- **use** `args` **instead of** `args.length === 0` ,
- **use** `args` **instead of** `args.length === 1` .